# Identify monitor mount interface

Tags: physical-wear

I have a monitor. It has a desktop stand, and I want to use a different mount (to put it on an adjustable arm).

I have seen monitors that have 4 bolts in the back (VESA). It does not have these. I am trying to workout what mount system it does use. Is it proprietary or a standard? Where can I check for options (I have searched but only found VESA and camera mounts (don't know why)).

[image: Image of existing mount, on the foot]
[image: Image of back of monitor: mount point]

Answer (score 0):

Your monitor is a HP pavilion 23CW

The mount seems to be proprietary. However there are adaptors available to convert it to VISA. Search: HP pavilion 23cw mount. Then you can use standard VISA arms.